# Translating rJAGS censored linear regression model to PyMC3

Tags: python, r, pymc3, jags, rjags

I'm currently attempting to translate a program my boss originally wrote in R/rJAGS to Python/PyMC3, partially because he wanted to see if it was something python could do, partially because I want to learn how to do this sort of thing, it seems like a good thing to know. I've gotten a linear fit model working in PyMC3, but I'm having difficulty trying to replicate the censoring bit.

The R program reads in a table, each line having three y-values for three specific x-values which are constant across the data set. Each y-value also has some error associated with it. If that were it then I have a PyMC3 model that can do that; here's the toy model I had set up for it:

```
import numpy as np
import pymc3 as pmc

# set random seed for reproducibility
np.random.seed(12345)

x = np.linspace(0,10,3)

# Make some model data
# Parameters for linear fit
slope_true = -0.2
inter_true = 0.1

#Linear function
linear = lambda x,slope,inter: slope*x+inter
f_true = linear(x=x,slope=slope_true, inter=inter_true )

# add noise to the data points
f = f_true + np.random.normal(size=len(x)) * 0.05 
f_error = np.ones_like(f_true)*f.max()*np.random.uniform(0,1,size=len(x))

with pmc.Model() as model3:
    slope = pmc.Normal('slope', mu=0, tau=0.4, testval= 0.15)
    inter = pmc.Normal('inter', mu=0, tau=40, testval=0.15)

    linear = pmc.Deterministic('linear', slope*x+inter)

    y = pmc.Normal('y', mu=linear, tau=1.0/f_error**2, observed=f)

    start = pmc.find_MAP()
    step = pmc.NUTS()
    trace = pmc.sample(1000,start=start)

# extract results
slope_fit = np.median(trace.slope)
slope_up = slope_fit - np.percentile(trace.slope, 15.9)
slope_dn = np.percentile(trace.slope, 84.1) - slope_fit
```

The above model was somewhat hacked together from examples I found online, it generates points on a line, adds a bit of noise and some "error", then performs a fit on the noisy points with error. After that it grabs the a median value for the slope and some errors associated with it.

But now I need to be able to account for these censored points that sometimes pop up. In this instance certain y-values may have been non-detections, so the value for that point is considered a censor limit and the point is then set to NaN, with an error still associated with the point. The R code model (saved as lin_regress_model.bug) which handles this looks like this:

```
model {
    for (i in 1:N) {
        isCensored[i] ~ dinterval(rv[i], censorLimitVec[i])
        rv[i] ~ dnorm(y[i],rve[i])
        y[i] <- a*x[i] + b
    }
    a ~ dnorm(0, 1e-6)
    b ~ dnorm(0, 1e-6)
    tau ~ dgamma(0.001, 0.001)
    sigma <- 1/sqrt(tau)
}
```

Here's an example of data it might get fed:

```
N = 3 # always 3, because 3 points
isCensored = c(False, False, True)
censorLimitVec = c(-6.65, -6.65, -6.65) # was value of 3rd point before NA
rv = c(-3.4, -4.7, NA) # y-values
rve = c(7e3, 7e2, 6.66) # these are Tau I think, like 1/sigma^2
x = c(0.15, 0.68, 0.94) # x-values
```

So all of those get passed into the jags model, and it's able to fit this censored data, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to translate that bit into PyMC3-speak. It sounds like the dinterval function in this may be similar to Uniform in PyMC3, but I don't really know what to do with that because I can't directly translate the formula lines (the concept of the tilde itself in R is still a bit weird to me).

If anyone out there can help me it would be greatly appreciated. For all I know it might not even be possible with PyMC3, or maybe it's easy and I've just missed something. Regardless, I've been banging my head against the wall for a few days now so I figure it'd be best just to ask for help at this point.